# State of the Art JSON formatting of relational data?

Tags: json

I have a question, I want to display a SQL Like Database with JSON. I have the following concept:

A Town have different People who live there. In SQL you will create 2 Tables. Town and People. The People will then have a TownID to get the reference to its town.

Now what is the better way to display it in JSON:

Way 1, in one structure

```
[
{"New York":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]},
{"San Francisco":[
    {"firstName":"Fred", "lastName":"Boening"}
]}
]
```

Way 2, SQL like

```
[
    {"City":"New York", "id":"0"}, 
    {"City":"San Francisco", "id":"1"}
]
[
    {"CityId": "0", "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"CityId": "0", "firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
    {"CityId": "0", "firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
    {"CityId": "1", "firstName":"Fred", "lastName":"Boening"}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your json would look like something like this

```
[
    {
        "cityName": "New York",
        "peoples": [
            {
                "firstName": "John",
                "lastName": "Doe"
            },
            {
                "firstName": "Anna",
                "lastName": "Smith"
            },
            {
                "firstName": "Peter",
                "lastName": "Jones"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "cityName": "San Francisco",
        "peoples": [
            {
                "firstName": "Fred",
                "lastName": "Boening"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Okay, this is the Way 1. So you would recommend to make one JSON file instead of two different like e.g. two different SQL Tables?

Comment: this approach is good when you want to display the list of peoples along with the city name. if you want to display first list of cities and then on some click or event on one city you make another call to get the list of people approach-2 fits.